# How give name Jenkins slave in instance EC2

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i have a litle problem. My Jenkins slave create new instance no name. Just blank field,and another blank is full. I tried creating a name in **Tags name** Jenkins, but I still can't assign an instance name. And is it possible to make Jenkins delete volumes after terminated of instance occurs?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirvi.png)

Comment: Are you saying you have a Jenkins job for creating EC2 instances and you want Jenkins to assign name to those instances?

Comment: Yes, I need Jenkins to assign a name for instance

Comment: I realized used "tags name"